# dynamic table in javaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am working on a table whit Java FX.this table need to be dynamic, and I don't mean populate it whit data from the DB.
what I need is a table that change columns ,depending on the value for a cell in the same row .
 any one got some idea how should I star ?

```
JAVAFX
```

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you describe is a table. What is the meaning of a column if it's only applicable to some rows? For example - if rows 1,2,4 need column X, and rows 3 and 5 need column Y, what column should be displayed? Is such a thing even a table?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of columns and the column ***value*** is modified depending on some other cell value or should columns be added/removed dynamically? Also a simple example would help.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in JavaFX. There's only a TableView. And that's what it is, a view of an existing datastructure.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible (and the question doesn't describe the expected behaviour thoroughly enough). The data structure displayed by the `TableView` **can** change and the columns can be modified. However `TableView` may not be the right class to do this depending on the exact requirements...

Comment: All UI components are views of existing data structures (sometimes in a trivial sense; nevertheless it is always true).

Comment: Nontheless people expect different from a table. And JavaFX fails at delivering that. The only thing worth mentioning is the controlsfx grid, but that can do so much that it's too buggy.

Comment: TBH I can't tell from the question what the OP expects here. If he merely wants the value in one column to be modified depending on the value in another column, then that's very possible.